# Offset date&time result by 3 hours

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code which queries the database:

```
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `ur_destination` WHERE `destination_name` IN ($id)");

echo "<table class='datagrid'>
<tr>
<td>Start date & time GMT</td>
<td>End date & time GMT</td>
</tr>
";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['active_period_start_time'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['active_period_end_time'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Result looks like this: 2014-04-27 10:50:00
So how can I add +3 hours offset to the result of both start & end time?
Thanks.

Comment: Use the PHP DateTime class.  Create a DateTIme based on the row result, add three hpurs and echo the DateTime object

Comment: Why dont you add it in the query directly?

Comment: Do you always want to just add some number of hours to the time, or do you want the time to be the appropriate time within a specific timezone? The two won't always be the same.

Comment: Yeah I just want to add 3 hours to the time result. I cannot modify the database so I just have to work with the result, if possible.

Comment: in sql you could do `active_period_start_time + INTERVAL 3 HOUR`

Comment: Check my uploaded answer for 3 hours add to your date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+3 hours",strtotime($row['active_period_start_time']))) . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+3 hours",strtotime($row['active_period_end_time']))). "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: That gives a syntax error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: It's the first one with strtotime. If I remove the ; from the end, the error just gets weirder with something like "T_ECHO"

Comment: I updated my answer there is one bracket missing now copy and paste my code and check

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Datetime object you can calculate the dates with the [modify](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.modify.php) operator.

So you can say:

```
$datet = new \Datetime();
$datet->modify('+3 hours');
```

Then you have in `$datet` the time +3 hours. Perhaps you should first read a bit about the date functions in PHP.

Or you use MySQL to calculate the fields in your where clause.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html